# Show/Hide Item According to Parameter in Trigger

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to show/hide an item (a button "PB") on a block (Block "A") according to a parameter. How can I do this in a trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little search more and it works.

`set_item_property('A.PB',DISPLAYED,property_false);`

`set_item_property('A.PB',DISPLAYED,property_true);`

Comment: yes, you can use as this way, also `displayed` could be replaced with `visible`.